# is it possible to "group by" data in an SSRS tablix?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a dataset that returns information on an individual - such as name - and all of the appointments that individual has.  I want to display two tablix (tablixes? tablii?) on my report - one that lists the individual sand another that lists the individuals and their appointments.

The only way I can seem to figure to do this is two separate datasets, but that just seems silly to me.  Plus the dataset takes a while to refresh, so it would double my query time.

Is there some way to get this individual list by using some sort of group by/distinct method that is eluding me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the same dataset, and set it up tablix one with just the "individual" field and then the second tablix would be "individual" by "appointment":

[image]